# Is Identity Column hold the duplicate values?

Tags: sql-server

I have the table with the identity column. This is looks like identity column is duplicated. What are all the possibilities that column hold the duplicate values.

Table structure looks like below,

```
  create table Table1(ID INT identity, value varchar(10))
```

Comment: if there is no unique constraint on that column, it is possible to get duplicates in it by using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON`

Comment: This is covered in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) in the documentation: *"The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following: **Uniqueness of the value** - Uniqueness must be enforced by using a **PRIMARY KEY** or **UNIQUE** constraint or **UNIQUE** index."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course and Identity Column can have Duplicate values.

But since the values are auto-populated by the Table itself, there is no chance that the Duplicates can be created by the system.

But you can add Duplicate values using the `INSERT INTO` Statement. or if you `RESEED` the identity column without removing the Existing values the system itself will create Duplicates.

because of The identity column in Not having a `UNIQUE` constraint by default.

see the below Example

```
CREATE TABLE Temp
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    MyStr VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO Temp
VALUES('A')
```

**Result**

```
SeqNo   MyStr
1         A

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TEMP ON

INSERT INTO TEMP(SeqNo,MyStr)
VALUES(1,'B')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TEMP OFF
```

**Result**

```
SeqNo   MyStr
1        A
1        B
```

Inserted Couple more records

```
INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES('C')

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES('D')
```

**Result**

```
SeqNo   MyStr
1        A
1        B
2        C
3        D
```

Perform identity Reseed and insert a New value

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TEMP', RESEED, 1)

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES('E')
```

**Final result**

```
SeqNo   MyStr
1        A
1        B
2        C
3        D
2        E
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations

Answer (score 3):

if the column has no unique constraint, it is possible to get duplicate values in it.
One way to do this is like this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON

INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, value)
VALUES (1, 'hello')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF
```

Another way is to reseed the table, check the answer of Satheesh on how to do that.

If you dont want that, make this column `primary key` or create an `unique constraint` on that column.

how to make a unique index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Table1_ID
ON dbo.Table1(ID)
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;
```

The `WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;` is needed in your example because you allow null values in the ID column, which I do not recommend

**I am reasonably sure your table should look like this**

```
Create table Table1 (
  ID int identity not null,
  Value varchar(10),
  constraint PK_Table1_ID primary key (ID)
)
```